# How to properly go to another webpage on button Click?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have created two interfaces `reportsview` and `mainview` (alias `widget.main`) : is it of good practice to go from the former to the latter (onClick) using this ExtJS logic :

```
var reportsViewInstance = Ext.getCmp('reportsview');
        
        if (reportsViewInstance) {
            reportsViewInstance.destroy();
            
        }

        var mainV2 = Ext.create('widget.main', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            hideMode: 'visibility'
        });

        mainV2.show();
```

Or do i have to call the `mainview` using another logic for instance using `getView()`... ?
Thanks for this clarification

Comment: You can use routing: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html

Comment: i am using routing through `this.redirect('main', true)` in the controller of the view. But to get to the target view how should the method be implemented ?

Comment: Please see this fiddle  :https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3aup it's not working but you got all the code i'm using . what i want to know is if it the correct way of switching views. thanks

Comment: You can use card layout for viewport and switch between items.

Comment: sure but i'd rather do it with panels. is my solution of good practice in ExtJS (to create and destroy separate view panels like i did)?

Comment: This question relates to mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010963/how-to-move-between-panels-in-sencha-touch

Comment: I agree with Arthur.  A card layout and switch the active panel seems to be the accepted approach.  The coworkee https://github.com/sencha-extjs-examples/Coworkee example uses this approach as to other examples.  If you are not going to reuse the panel, that is it will never be viewed again then you can destroy the panel, otherwise just update the data being displayed.

Comment: I can't use a card layout in my case. i created two panels extending viewports so to display them based on their routes : i create and destroy based on the current view and the view i want to go to